# Newsletter preview doesn’t respect responsive design

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, community-digests

The site newsletter preview doesn't respect [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). In particular: the left part of the popup isn't visible at all; scrolling to the right doesn't darken the background.

All necessary details should be visible in the image below:

> [image]